# "Invalid date" parsing date with moment.js

Tags: javascript, date, parsing, momentjs

I'm trying to calculate the relative date from a given one like the following

**Mon Nov 21 11:48:33 CET 2016**

I think the given date follows this pattern:

**EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy**

So, I'm trying to get the relative date with this line:

```
moment("Mon Nov 21 11:48:33 CET 2016", "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy").fromNow();
```

But I'm receiving an "Invalid date"...

I've changed the "EEE" for "ddd" following some advices but then I'm getting a bad relative date.

**moment("Mon Nov 21 12:30:40 CET 2016", "ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy").fromNow()** > **20 days ago**

Any idea about what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Are you including [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/)? If not, that `z` format specifier is invalid. (I'm not 100% sure `zzz` is valid for parsing even if you are...)

Comment: Also, `EEE` should be `ddd`.

Comment: yes just adding ddd instead of EEE will make it right

Comment: Yes, the moment-timezone (0.5.9 version) is included...

Comment: If I add "ddd" instead of "EEE" I get a bad relative date... With **moment("Mon Nov 21 12:30:40 CET 2016", "ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy").fromNow()** i get **20 days ago**

Comment: @Ivan: That's because you've used `d` where you wanted `D` or `DD`. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) in addition to Moment, there are a few problems:

1. `zzz` is <s>invalid</s> undocumented; it's just `z`. (It seems to be allowed, though.)
2. `EEE` is invalid. `E` is for day numbers. You wanted `ddd` (day name). See [the documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/).
3. You've also used `d` (day name) where you wanted `D` or `DD` (day of month number). Again, see the docs linked above.

This works with moment+moment-timezone:

```
moment("Mon Nov 21 11:48:33 CET 2016", "ddd MMM D HH:mm:ss z yyyy").fromNow();
// -------------------------------------^^^-----^----------^
```

Example:

```js
console.log(moment("Mon Nov 21 11:48:33 CET 2016", "ddd MMM D HH:mm:ss z yyyy").fromNow());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.16.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.9/moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.min.js"></script>
```

**However**, I don't think Moment supports parsing that `z`, because I can't find anything in the Moment Timezone docs saying it enhances parsing, and when I run the above, it acts as though the date/time is in my timezone (GMT), not CET; and in fact I can swap in any timezone indicator I want (EST, PST, etc.) and it still treats the string as my local time.

Answer (score 0):

For Day of the week use ddd

Check http://momentjs.com/docs/  for more information on formats.

```js
console.log(moment("Mon Nov 21 11:48:33 CET 2016", "ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy").fromNow());
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.16.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```